# javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException but data is present

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save `User` entity using spring data jpa in spring boot web (1.5.4) project.
Some fields of `User` entity have `@NotEmpty`, `@NotNull` annotations for validation purposes
So, when I save `User` with populated data the hibernate tells me that fields which marked with `@NotEmpty`, `@NotNull` require data. But how it is possible? Data exists! I have checked it in debug mode.

Then I moved forward and debuged hibernate sources. It appeared that `org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(..)` method were invoked from 
`org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert()` 2 times
First time with data inside `User`, second - with `null` values inside `User`.
This second time rised `ConstraintViolationException`

The question is why it happens and how to fix it?

`User` entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table( name = "user",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
        })
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @NotEmpty(message = "First name is required")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name is required")
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Email is required")
    @Email(message = "Email is invalid")
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "UserName is required")
    @Size(min = 4, max = 30)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="enabled", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int default 1")
    private int enable = 1;

    @NotNull(message="Password invalid")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password is required")
    @Size(max=60)
    private String password;

    @Lob
    private String summary;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id")
    @NotNull
    private Rol role;

    /*
    some other fields without @Notnull and @NotEmpty, but with @OneToMany (@JoinTable), @ManyToOne (@JoinColumn) relations 

   getters and setters, generated by lombok
*/
}
```

`Role`

```
@Entity
@Data
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class Rol implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    /*
        getters and setters generated by lombok
    */

}
```

`UserRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    User findByEmail(String email);

    User findUserByUsernameAndIdIsNot(String username, Long id);

    User findById(Long id);

    List<User>findAll();

    Boolean existsByUsernameAndIdIsNot(String username, Long id);

    Boolean existsByEmailAndIdIsNot(String email, Long id);
}
```

JSON body in POST request maps by means of maptruct from DTO to User
`JSON request`

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "",
  "firstName": "Potato",
  "lastName": "test 1",
  "email": "potato1@gmail.com",
  "username": "potato",
  "enable": 1,
  "password": "12345678",
  "photoURL": "12345678",
  "summary": "",
  "role": {
    "id": 4
  }

}
```

`Response`

```
{
"timestamp": 1587355579867,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException",
"message": "Validation failed for classes [com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='UserName is required', propertyPath=username, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='UserName is required'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Password is required', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='Password is required'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Password invalid', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='Password invalid'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Last name is required', propertyPath=lastName, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='Last name is required'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='First name is required', propertyPath=firstName, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='First name is required'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Email is required', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='Email is required'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=role, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'} ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=username, rootBeanClass=class com.domain.MyProject.Entities.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'} ]",
"path": "/api/user/save"
}
```

List of Technologies used:

- Spring Boot Starter Web 1.5.4 Release
- Spring Starter data jpa 1.5.4 Release (1.11.4 Release inside)
- **hibernate-core 5.0.12.Final**
- **hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.12.Final**
- **hibernate-validator 5.3.5.Final**
- Spring Security 4.2.3 Release
- Embedded Tomcat
- mapstruct 1.3.0.Beta2
- Lombok
- Gradle 4.4.1 with 2.7 wrapper
- more [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/DSViYW78)

Does anyone have some idea about how to fix this strange issue?

p.s. moving to newer version of spring boot and spring data is not an option for now since project has massive functionality already implemented based on that versions of spring

**UPDATED:**
`UserController`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserServices userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

     @PostMapping("/save")
    public  ResponseEntity<MessageResponse> saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserViewModel user){

        if (userRepository.existsByUsernameAndIdIsNot(user.getUsername(), user.getId())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(MessageResponse.of("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByEmailAndIdIsNot(user.getEmail(), user.getId())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(MessageResponse.of("Error: Email is already in use!"));
        }

        Pair<String, User> result = userService.saveUser(user);
        if(result.getSecond() == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(MessageResponse.of(result.getFirst()), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

        return  new ResponseEntity<>(MessageResponse.of(result.getFirst()), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

`UserServices`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServices {
    @Autowired
   private UserRepository UserRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RolServices rolServices;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    //...

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private UserMapper mapper
            = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    public Pair<String, User> saveUser(UserViewModel vm){
        if (vm.getId() > 0L) {
            return updateUser(vm);
        } else {
            User savedUser = userRepository.findByUsername(vm.getUsername());

            if ( savedUser != null){
                return Pair.of("The user you are trying to save already exist", null);
            }
            User resultUser = mapper.mapToEntity(vm);
            resultUser.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(resultUser.getPassword()));
            if (resultUser.getRole().getId() == Roles.ROLE_STUDENT.ordinal() || resultUser.getRole().getId() == Roles.ROLE_FREE_STUDENT.ordinal()){
                resultUser.setName(resultUser.getFirstName() + ' ' + resultUser.getLastName());
            }
            User result = userRepository.save(resultUser);
            if (result == null){
                return Pair.of("Couldn't save the user", null);
            } else {
                return  Pair.of("User saved successfully", result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add code of controller ?

Comment: make sure the setters are correctly implemented and maybe test locally with a validator and some unit tests, might be easier to check if validation fails or transfering the data doesn't work correctly.
On another note I wouldn't recommend using an entity in a rest interace, there should be another layer inbetween.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but: "moving to newer version of spring boot and spring data is not an option for now since project has massive functionality already implemented based on that versions of spring" is a reason for staying up to date with your library and framework versions. Not for letting your application rot.

Comment: Dear @JensSchauder, there are different customers with their budget and time restrictions. It is sad that you do not understand this and allow yourself to write such comments

Comment: I very well understand budget and time restrictions. That is exactly why, when you have an application of high value you need to maintain it properly.

Comment: From the code you provided I see you actually have a UserViewModel, could you explain why the Constraints are on your entity and not on the ViewModel?